# INSERT or IGNORE with unique constraints doesn't work

Tags: python, sqlite

The design of my db is following.

```
    combinations_sql = """
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS combinations 
    (id integer PRIMARY KEY, 
    city text NOT NULL, 
    industry text NOT NULL,
    round text,
    result int,
    CONSTRAINT unq UNIQUE (city, industry, round)
    )
    """
```

The combination of city, industry, round is unique and when I need to add new data I want to check whether the data has already exist in my db

So far I use INSERT or IGNORE

```
    combinations_sql = """
    INSERT OR IGNORE INTO combinations (city, industry, round, result) VALUES (?,?,?,?)
    """
```

But I'm not sure about correctness of this approach. When I add new parameters they still appear in db although they shouldn't.

EDIT:
My workaround that solved the problem but the performance is worser:

```
    combinations_sql = """
    SELECT * FROM combinations WHERE city = ? AND industry = ?
    """
    cursor.execute(combinations_sql, (city,industry))
    entry = cursor.fetchone()

    if entry is None:
        combinations_sql = """
        INSERT INTO combinations (city, industry , round, result) VALUES (?,?,?, ?)
        """
        cursor.execute(combinations_sql, (city, industry, round, result))
        print("Entry added")
    else:
        print("Entry found")
```

Comment: Are you sure `INSERT OR IGNORE` is the correct syntax?  All the examples I see just use `INSERT IGNORE`.

Comment: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html

Comment: When you insert a row that ought to be a duplicate, are you sure the text values are identical, i.e. same spacing, capitalization, etc?

Comment: Have you inspected the table to verify the constraint is present and active?

Comment: @JohnGordon Yeah, I test on a dummy example